# c++ compiled object files and internal identifiers

Tags: c++, compilation, linkage, nm

i read [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Programming_Languages/C%2B%2B/Code/Compiler/Linker#Linkage) that

> A function with internal linkage is only visible inside one translation unit. When the compiler compiles a function with internal linkage, the compiler writes the machine code for that function at some address and puts that address in all calls to that function (which are all in that one translation unit), but strips out all mention of that function in the ".o" file.

i compiled this code

```
int g_i{};          //extern
static int sg_i{};    //static

static int add(int a, int b) //internal linakge!
{
    return a+b;
}

int main()
{
    static int s_i{}; //static - local
    int a_i{};        //auto - local
    a_i = add(1,2);
    return 0;
}
```

and compiled using `g++ -c` and created my `main.o` file
then trying `nm -C main.o` im getting this result:

```
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
                 U __main
0000000000000000 t add(int, int)
0000000000000004 b sg_i
0000000000000008 b main::s_i
0000000000000000 B g_i
0000000000000014 T main
```

can you please explain why those internal identifier are still mentioned in the object file while i heard that linker using these object files will have no idea about their existence?

thanks.

Comment: Because the book is simplifying it. The linker knows the function is there but it ignores it. Debuggers still need to know there is a function. If there's an error in the function the linker needs to know which function the error is in.

Comment: so what explained there is not what really is happening.

Comment: Please read `nm` manual about the difference between `T` and `t`, between `B` and `b`.

Comment: @273K oh in the page i found there was simple 1 explanations for both, i thought there should be no important differentce. i missed this part "If lowercase, the symbol is local; if uppercase, the symbol is global (external)." thanks

Answer (score 1):

The linker knows that there is such function. However it also knows that the function that the function with internal linkage is **only** visible in the translation that translation unit. More simply, it just forbids the call of that function outside the translation unit.

That's why you need those internal identifiers, so that the linker knows that this function belongs only to this translation unit.